# Datatables Button Collection - How to Use Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, datatables

I'm trying to add a dropdown to my datatable to show buttons like this :

[image]

My code :

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require("jquery");
    // boostrap
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

var datatableSettings = {
    select: {
      style: "multi",
      selector: "td:first-child",
    },
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: {
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: "collection",
          text: "Export",
          buttons: [
            { extend: "csv" },
            { extend: "excel" },
            {
              extend: "pdfHtml5",
              orientation: "landscape",
              pageSize: "A0",
              title: "Users List PDF",
              exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                  page: "current",
...
  },
```

My problem is that the dropdown is shown but it doesn't work : i can't open the dropdown when i click on export to show the buttons inside

[image: Dropdown Menu]

Comment: How is it not working? Can you provide more information?

Comment: i can't open the dropdown to show buttons inside

Comment: Can you create a snippet where this reproduces?

Comment: i can't coz i have many dependencies and it's a big project , the problem that i don't got any console problem and when i click on the export button i can't show other buttons

Comment: Khaled you need to create a minimal reproducible example. Without that we cannot guess what your project contains and why is that wrong. First you need to understand what your problem is and then present that as a digestible information to us. Usually the sheer fact that you force yourself to ask a question properly leads you to the answer.

Comment: this is a minimal example of what i want to do:  https://jsfiddle.net/khaledboussoffara/854m3kb1/1/#&togetherjs=eBKhLa1pEE   . all i need is to show "csv" and "pdf" buttons inside "export" dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a full configuration for making collection dropdown works :

I'm using symfony webpack :

In js file :

```
import "./styles/datatables.scss";
const $ = require("jquery");
const routes = require("../public/js/fos_js_routes.json");
import Routing from "../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js";
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css");
require("@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js");
Routing.setRoutingData(routes);

// this "modifies" the jquery module: adding behavior to it
// the bootstrap module doesn't export/return anything
require("bootstrap");
require("bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip");
window.jQuery = window.$ = require("jquery");
require("datatables.net");
require("datatables.net-dt");
require("datatables.net-bs5");
require("jszip");
require("pdfmake");
require("datatables.net-buttons-bs5");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js");
require("datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js");
require("datatables.net-scroller-bs5");
require("datatables.net-select-bs5");
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
$(document).ready(function () {
  var startupsDt = null;
  var managersDt = null;
  var promosDt = null;
  var domainsDt = null;
  var datatableSettings = {
    select: {
      style: "multi",
      selector: "td:first-child",
    },
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    buttons: {
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: "collection",
          text: "Export",
          buttons: [
            { extend: "csv" },
            { extend: "excel" },
            {
              extend: "pdfHtml5",
              orientation: "landscape",
              pageSize: "A0",
              title: "Users List PDF",
              exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                  page: "current",
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        /*   {
          extend: "copy",
          className: "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate",
        }, */
      ],
      // dom: {
      //   button: {
      //     tag: "button",
      //     className: "btn-primary mx-2 my-2 align-middle btn-sm ",
      //   },
      //   buttonLiner: {
      //     tag: "null",
      //   },
      // },
    },
    responsive: true,
    ordering: false,
    pageLength: 10,
    paginate: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    searching: false,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    sAjaxDataProp: "data",
    oLanguage: {
      sProcessing:
        '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center py-2"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>\n',
      sSearch: "Rechercher",
      sLengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
      sInfo:
        '<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert"> Affichage des &eacute;lements <span class="badge badge-info"> _START_ </span> &agrave; <span class="badge badge-info"> _END_ </span> sur <span class="badge badge-info"> _TOTAL_ </span> &eacute;l&eacute;ments </div>',
      sInfoEmpty:
        "Affichage des &eacute;lements 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
      sInfoFiltered: "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
      sInfoPostFix: "",
      sLoadingRecords: '<i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>\n',
      sZeroRecords: "Aucun &eacute;l&eacute;ment &agrave; afficher",
      sEmptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
      oPaginate: {
        sFirst: "Premier",
        sPrevious: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
        sNext: "Suivant",
        sLast: "Dernier",
      },
      oAria: {
        sSortAscending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
        sSortDescending:
          ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant",
      },
    },
    columns: null,
    ajax: null,
  };
```

In the sass or css file don't forget to add :

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css";
@import "~datatables.net-buttons-bs5/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css";
```

Finally i got :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the `text` attribute and you do not need to specify the `extend` attribute, unless you want to have dropdown buttons in the collection. This worked for me:

```
          buttons: [
            {
              extend: "collection",
              text: "Export",
              buttons: [
                { text: "csv" },
                { text: "excel" },
                {
                  text: "pdf",
                  orientation: "landscape",
                  pageSize: "A0",
                  title: "Users List PDF",
                  exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                      page: "current",
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2c9s0o7/

Comment: thank you so much for helping me , i'm really gratful , just i will post a full solution for that

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara I'm happy the issue was resolved.

Comment: thank you so much, can you take a look at my last question please ?

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara what happens if you have `event.stopPropagation()` inside the event? You already have a `preventDefault` call, but that may be not enough.

Comment: all the datatable is rerendred and the form is reset with empty input value, i'm not able right now to apply filter value when click submit

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara this very much sounds like a full postback.

Comment: i don't know what is "postback" can you explain to me please?  and actually the simple solution i'm using is to put the form before the datatable and seperated from the datatable

Comment: @KhaledBoussoffara your form is submitted to the server and once the server responds, the web-page is reloaded. This is what you may call a postback. Instead, you would probably like to only send a message, receive some data and refresh only the controls that you would like to refresh. So, you need an AJAX request instead of a full postback. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback